# rails - where to store writeable system-wide variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've had a read of similar questions and not found a simple answer. I need to store a date value that has nothing to do with my models.

For example, let's say I have a screen which displays a graph of user activity based on all records being created after a specific date. I need to store that date somewhere. An admin user will change this initial date depending on whether they need to look at the last six months, or the last year etc. That setting will then be the same for all admin users. So it's not an admin user setting.

I thought about a config file, but then it needs to be writable and these seem idea for values that are being looked up but not edited on a regular basis?

Any advice appreciated..

Comment: an `admin_setting` model could do the trick

Comment: Why does it even have to be a global setting? This sounds like something which should be done with a query parameter to the graph endpoint, don't build non RESTful state into your app unless there is absolutely no other good alternative.

Comment: `/admin/users/activity?start_date=1407327732 `